# Как получить содержимое строки до пробела. python

Tags: python

У меня есть строка 'hello world'. Мне нужно разбить эту строку на строки 'hello' и 'world', и эти части вписать в разные массивы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
s = 'hello world'

print(s.split())
```